# Maximum transfer rate isochronous 128B endpoint full speed

Tags: usb

In the usb specification (Table 5-4) is stated that given an isochronous endpoint with a maxPacketSize of 128 Bytes as much as 10 transactions can be done per frame. This gives 128 * 10 * 1000 = 1.28 MB/s of theorical bandwidth.
At the same time it states

> The host must not issue more than 1 transaction in a single frame for a specific isochronous endpoint.

Isn't it contradictory with the aforementioned table ?

I've done some tests and found that only 1 transaction is done per frame on my device. Also, I found on several web sites that just 1 transaction can be done per frame(ms). Of course I suppose the spec is the correct reference, so my question is, what could be the cause of receiving only 1 packet per frame ? Am I misunderstanding the spec and what i think are transactions are actually another thing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The host must not issue more than 1 transaction in a single frame for a specific isochronous endpoint.

Assuming USB Full Speed you could still have 10 isochronous 128 byte transactions per frame by using 10 *different* endpoints.

The Table 5-4 seems to miss calculations for chapter 5.6.4 "Isochronous Transfer Bus Access Constraints". The 90% rule reduces the max number of 128 byte isochr. transactions to nine.